# pygtk global label style

Tags: python, styles, gtk

I am working with python and gtk.

Is it possible to create global Styles?
I want to make the text in all Labels in a Window red and bold.
Please give a code exapmple.

EDIT 1:
It has to work on Windows, too.

EDIT 2:
my actual code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    import gtk
    import db
    import datetime
    import gobject
    import pango

    class ReportNew(gobject.GObject):

            __gsignals__ = {"update-db": (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, gobject.TYPE_NONE,())}

            def __init__(self):
                    # Basics
                    self.__gobject_init__()
                    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
                    self.window.connect("destroy",self.destroy)
                    self.window.set_default_size(800,400)
                    self.window.set_title("WINDOW")

                    screen = gtk.gdk.Screen.get_default()
                    css_provider = gtk.CssProvider()
                    css_provider.load_from_path('style.css')
                    context = gtk.StyleContext()
                    context.add_provider_for_screen( screen,
                                            css_provider,
                                            gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER
                                            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a selector to specify which widgets are affected by the stylesheet.

```
from gi.repository import Gdk as gdk

screen = gdk.Screen.get_default()

css_provider = gtk.CssProvider()
css_provider.load_from_path('/path/to/file.css')

context = gtk.StyleContext()
context.add_provider_for_screen( screen,
                                 css_provider,
                                 gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER
                                 )
```

Create `/path/to/file.css`

```
/* Set background on GtkLabel
* and other types inheriting from
* it
*/
GtkLabel {
  background-color: red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: If i try this, following error is raising:
    AttributeError: 'gtk.Window' object has no attribute 'setStyleSheet'

Comment: I believe with Gdk you meant gtk.gdk... But that doesn't work: AttributeError: type object 'gtk.gdk.Screen' has no attribute 'get_default'

I couldn't find this in http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkscreen.html, either.

Comment: @ X.Jacobs: Done. I'm developing on Ubuntu, but is has to work on Windows, too!

Comment: add `from gi.repository import Gdk as gdk` and change `screen` to `screen = gdk.Screen.get_default()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20839/discussion-between-x-jacobs-and-happyhacking)